# Create and manipulate height-map, save as greyscale texture

Tags: texturing, export

I need to create a height-map and pass it into a custom shader in Unity3D.

I can pass it into the shader as a greyscale texture.

I believe I can create a height-map in Blender by starting out with a 100x100 (say) grid, restricting movement to only the vertical axis, then I can use stock tools to mould the surface.

But now is there any tool that can export the resultant height-map as a greyscale texture?

Would I have to write my own using Python?

Answer (score 6):

You can use *Displacement baking*.

1. Create your base grid/plane, create a new blank image and UV unwrap the plane onto it, then duplicated it.
2. Model/sculpt the plane (if you are using sculpting and not using dyntopo, you may want to use the multires modifier. See below).
3. Select the sculpted/deformed plane and the duplicate (still just a flat plane), so that the flat plane is the active object.
4. Enable *Selected to active* in *Render settings > Bake* and set the bake mode to *Displacement*. If your sculpted plane goes more than half a BU above or below the duplicated plane, you may want to enable *Normalize*.
5. Press *Bake*. Note that currently have BI selected as the current render engine to bake textures, however this is will be available for cycles in 2.71.

Result:

[image]

## Multires

If you are going to use sculpting, you could also use the *Multires modifier*. See [This post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/8685/599).

1. Add plane, create image, UV unwrap, and add multires modifier in simple mode.
2. Sculpt details
3. Set the *Preview* subdivision level to zero, then bake with *Bake from multires* enabled:

   [image]

---

## Cycles baking

Even before 2.71 comes out, it is possible to do this in cycles by rendering your terrain top down (with an orthographic camera) and with the Z position mapped to a gradient.

See [this post for details](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7199/599).

Comment: Heightmap seems to be inverted (usually it goes from black/low/(0,0,0), to white/high/(255,255,255)). Make sure the normals are pointing the right direction and select the other way around (sculpted and then the plane which is uv-mapped) :).

Comment: Oops. You are right, thanks for the correction :)