# Can Blender make alphas?

Tags: image, transparency

This is something I did a lot in Zbrush; make a black & white image containing height map data from a viewport snapshot.

Since I don't own Zbrush, I'd like to do this in Blender if possible. Is there a way?

I'm a big fan of Blender's sculpting tools (and Substance Painter), and this would benefit me greatly.

Comment: Yes, this definitely sounds possible, though not knowing what an "alpha" is in the context of zbrush, I'm not sure how best to translate that to blender. I can think of a couple different approaches to "create a heightmap from a model", but I don't know which works best for what you want to do. By "snapshot", do you mean an actual screenshot? Or..? If a little setup is acceptable, [one way is to use cycles](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7199/599)

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46620/how-to-make-a-brush-alpha-image-using-cycles/46629#46629

Comment: do a google image search for Zbrush alphas and you'll see what I'm talking about. In Zbrush you can sculpt on a surface, make it face the camera, and take a snapshot of the viewport as a black & white image, creating a stamp that can be used for future sculpting and painting. I'd like to make these in Blender if it's possible but I'm not sure how.